# Getting the POST XML of a web service request from the handling web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

(I'm new to web services so I may confuse some terms here.)

I made an asmx web service in visual studio with one method (with the attribute WebMethod) that takes a lot of parameters. Server-side, this is supposed to do stuff with the parameters and store them in a database.

Since there are a lot of parameters (dozens) and most of them won't usually be used, only some of the parameters are stored in separate columns, and the rest are supposed to be stored as XML, presumably the same XML that the web service receives the parameters in - the SOAP POST like the sample one shown when the service is run on local host.

But that XML is unpacked automatically into parameters and I don't know how to find the original XML. What's the simplest/fastest way to access that XML? Preferably only updating the handling method.

Sample C# code for context:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WebService_blip : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string Blip(int param1, int param2, string param3, /*... , */ string param40)
    {
        // code using parameters
        string requestXml = "blip"; // todo: where do I get relevant XML?
        // updating database
    }
}
```

XML I'm trying to put in the string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Blip xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <param1>int</param1>
      <param2>int</param2>
      <param3>string</param3>
      <!--...-->
      <param3>string</param3>
    </Blip>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use asmx web services for new code.  Microsoft [acknowledged](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%e2%80%9clegacy-technology%e2%80%9d/) seven years ago that asmx web services is a legacy technology.

Comment: @ClintB I could look into WCF, the web service is supposed to be pretty simple so it was an arbitrary decision. Is it easier to get the XML in WCF?